# Utilizing the template hierarchy while storing page templates in a subdirectory

Tags: page-template, template-hierarchy

I'd like to store the page templates for my theme in their own directory, `/pages/` for example.

I'd also like to utilize the `page-{slug}.php` functionality of the Template Hierarchy, and not have to set my page templates manually in the WP dashboard.

There doesn't seem to be a filter for where WP looks up the page templates, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -2):

It is tricky. I found the answer within a different thread here.

[WordPress Custom Page Template in a different directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30281/wordpress-custom-page-template-in-a-different-directory)

Comment: Rather mark posts as duplicates than simply just posting a link to a question with an answer

Comment: Got it! I was not aware about it. Actually I am making my self familiar with this great website.